# What rule is used in the factorization $z^5 - 1 = (z - 1)(z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, geometric-progressions

What rule used in the following factorization? Could anyone tell me please?
$$z^5 - 1 = (z - 1)(z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1)$$

Comment: Factor theorem.

Comment: what is the Factor theorem? what is its statement ?@Idonknow

Comment: The rule that $(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-k-1}$

Comment: Please type the question rather than posting an images.  Images cannot be searched.

Comment: You should read about the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^n-1 = (z-1)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+z^{n-3}...+z^1+1)$

$z^n+1 = (z+1)(z^{n-1}-z^{n-2}+z^{n-3}...-z^1+1)$ (For n is odd.)

Comment: This is actually what I was asking about, thank u sooo much for understanding me.

Comment: As I am solving a GRE exam, so time is crucial.

Comment: I think $n$ can be even as well (for the first equation).

Comment: Are you solving GRE maths subject test question?

Comment: @AlexVong Thanks.

Comment: @Idonknow  yes, I am solving Exam 0568.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a sum of a geometric progression:

For $z\neq1$ we obtain:
$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=\frac{z^5-1}{z-1},$$
which gives $$z^5-1=(z-1)(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1),$$ which is true also for $z=1$ and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply it out and check it.

If you mean how did someone guess that it could be factored like that?  Well, $z^5 -1$ has the obvious root of $1$ so $(z - 1)$ must be a factor. You can divide polynomials in a process similar to long division of integers.  Since, we know in advance that $(z - 1)$ is a factor, we should get no remainder.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the Ruffini's rule: 1 is a zero of $z^5-1$, 
then

```
$1 0 0 0 0 -1  (=1z^5+0z^4+0z^3+0z^2+0z-1)$
```

$1     1 1 1 1  1$
    $1 1 1 1 1  0$

result of the division by $(z-1)$:
 $1z^4+1z^3+1z^2+1z+1$

Comment: Sorry I couldn't type my answer properly

Comment: yes, frankly it is not clear for me.

Comment: See https://clasesdematesdemarta.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/ruffinis_rule-1287767540.pdf, particularly point 3) Factor theorem