# Better method to show $-x^3 + 1 = (-x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a rule, algorithm, or theorem used for this equality below:

$$-x^3 + 1 = (-x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$$

I know the RHS can be established using trial and error distributing the first term through the second, or alternatively same with FOIL.  I'm curious if there is a better method?

Image below from a CAS.

[image: a]

Comment: Look into [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Comment: Are you ware of the first n terms of geometric series ?if so try to use it here

Comment: "better" might be subjective.

Comment: Have you heard of the factor theorem, or more general remainder theorem?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2339212

Comment: "trial and error" ??

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore this is the eq for the first 3 terms, question is changing form per CAS output

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$S_n:=1+x+x^2+\cdots x^n.$$

Then *mentally*, by cancellation of the terms,

$$S_n-xS_n=1-x^{n+1},$$

and of course,

$$S_n-xS_n=(1-x)S_n.$$

Answer (score 1):

If two $n$th degree polynomials agree on $n+1$ points, then the polynomials are equal.  You have $3$rd-degree polynomials, so choose $4$ nice values for $x$ and plug them in on both sides.  How about $x=-1, 0, 1,$ and $2$.   If you get the same value on both sides all four times, the polynomials are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The factor theorem states that if $f(a)=0$ for some polynomial $f(x)$ then $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Try applying that to your case by letting $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1-x^3=1^3-x^3$$

In general, we have$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^{k}$$

$a-b$ is clearly a factor of $a^n-b^n$ as when $a=b$, $a^n-b^n$ vanishes.

Another way is to view $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^{k}$ as a geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive cube root of unity, then $\zeta^3=1,\zeta^2+\zeta+1=0$ and hence $1-x^3=-(x^3-1)=-(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)=(1-x)(x^2-(\zeta+\zeta^2)x+\zeta^3)=(1-x)(x^2+x+1)$

Note: FOIL, which is the distributive property of multiplication and addition, is unavoidable in pretty much any proof. To try to avoid using FOIL in a proof would be like trying to avoid using the fact that $1+1=2\ne 0$ in a field of characteristic $\gt 2$ or $0$.

Comment: $-(x^3 - 1) = -(x-1)(x-\gamma)(x-\gamma^2)$?

Comment: I don't get your question

Comment: $1 + 1 = 2$ is also true in a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: @RobArthan but then 2=0

Comment: Exactly: that's the definition of characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the base-$10$ numeration,

$$\color{green}{9\cdot111=999}.$$

This translates

$$(10-1)(10^2+10+1)=10^3-1.$$

---

More generally, in the base $x=w+1$,

$$\color{green}{w\cdot111=www}$$ or $$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1.$$

---

This immediately generalizes to higher degrees.